# Prevent Page Expanding Frame in Windows 8 XAML App within ScrollView

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I'm creating a basic application to test some functionality in a XAML based Windows 8 app.

I have created the following structure to simplify my example but in the real app it'll be more complex:

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="ScrollingTest.Xaml.MainPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScrollingTest.Xaml"
    xmlns:common="using:ScrollingTest.Xaml.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer
            HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#FF0BC8FF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" >

                <Frame Content="Frame" Name="theFrame" Margin="100" Width="3000" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The page, which is loaded into the Frame is of variable height (it contains a listview).

The issue is that as the height of the sub-page increases, so does the height of the ScrollViewer, meaning that the content is forced off the bottom of the screen.

What I'd want to achieve is horizontal scrolling for the parent but then use vertical scrolling on the sub-page.  In the real application there will be many sub-pages, probably within a grid.

It seems that putting the frame inside a ScrollViewer breaks the frame's internal scrolling capabilities.

If anyone could let me know of either a better way to achieve my end result or of some property I need to change then I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution from the following comment:
[XAML: Limiting size of control nested in ScrollViewer (to scroll nested within the ScrollViewer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755515/xaml-limiting-size-of-control-nested-in-scrollviewer-to-scroll-nested-within-t#comment24219502_16762752)

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

Not really what I wanted as this doesn't cope automatically when changing the orientation but it will have to do.

The other option is to handle the SizeChanged event of the page and update the height from the event handler (`theFrame.Height = scrollViewer.ActualHeight`).  That way it copes with changing the orientation as well.